# Is there a term for a free ride without consent?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think there should be a specific term for someone getting a free ride without consent, but I keep thinking of the word "hijack" which clearly isn't correct.

Examples include jumping on a train without a ticket, or riding without consent on the back of a truck. Or perhaps I want to sit in on someone else's meeting and just observe.

Am I gatecrashing? Or going along for a free ride?

Equally, if I hop on the roof of a train to get somewhere for free, is there a term for that?

Comment: freeloading....

Comment: I wouldn't use a travel metaphor for sitting in on someone else's meeting to observe. I'd just call myself an observer.

Comment: @PaulJohnson it's more to convey that I'd just riding along in the meeting, I should clarify the meeting is more a demo - and I'd like to just sit in a watch, although it's not that important that I do... Hence a free ride along, whilst stowaway is perfect for the travel part, hitching along is probably correct in this context...

Comment: @RemarkLima: Ahh. Perhaps you could just say "I'm just here for the ride", or "tagging along" (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tag-along). "Stowaway" would imply you were sneaking in without permission.

Comment: "I want to sit in on someone else's meeting and just observe"... if you do this without any invitation, indeed you'd be gatecrashing.

Comment: If you're just observing a meeting with no input you could say that you're a *fly on the wall*

Comment: There is the term "Freighthopping" specifically for the act of surreptitiously hitching a ride on a freight train : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freighthopping

Comment: *Turnstile Jumping* is the term in use specifically for subways

Comment: In education, sitting in on another class is called *auditing*.

Comment: You can (legally) jump on some trains and buses without a ticket.  When the conductor asks for your ticket, he will sell you one.  If the conductor does not get around to you before your destination station, you have a free ride.  It is good for short trips or when the train is especially crowded.

Comment: To answer your last question: yes, there is a specific term for "hopping on the roof of a train to get somewhere for free", it's called [trainsurfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_surfing).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

A [stowaway](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stowaway) is:

> a person who hides aboard a vehicle, ship, or aircraft in order to gain free passage

(Collins Online Dictionary)

From Alexander Rein's *The Blue Streak: A Hacker's Guide to Special Relativity:*

> For example, if a railroad train is passing by a bystander who is very close to the tracks and at the same time a stowaway on top of a railroad car is running in the forward direction, the Velocity of the stowaway relative to the bystander is simply the sum of the two Velocities: the ground velocity of the train and the Velocity of the stowaway relative to the train.

Comment: I think you nailed it. The word even applies to a free ride inside the airplane wheel well. +1)

Comment: A more train-specific term would be **hobo**.

Comment: Yes but as a native speaker (AmE) I'd not use *stowaway* for hiding or being uninvited in the back of a truck or an automobile. The vehicle needs to be a large vehicle with plenty of places to hide.

Comment: @GoDucks if the driver sees you and doesn't kick you off, then you are now there with the drivers permission. Ergo you are hiding from the driver.

Comment: This is great, but I'd say that a `stowaway` definitely stresses the "hiding away" part - I wouldn't use the word for a fare dodger on public transport; that person isn't hiding at all, they've just been crafty and eluded the payment system.  Otherwise, they just look like a normal traveller.

Comment: @Rathony I believe the correct term for attempting to grab a free ride by way of an airplane wheel well is “suicide”. That little area would be neither pressurized, nor climate controlled.

Comment: @Morgen: Nevertheless, some people have done it and survived, notably including the story all over the headlines a few years ago of a 5 year old boy who survived a wheel-well flight from L.A. to Hawaii.  It's obviously a terrible idea, but not necessarily lethal...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Huh, I should probably stop being so amazed when people survive things that should rightly kill them.

Comment: Seems good for most of OPs examples except, "... I want to sit in on someone else's meeting and just observe."

Answer (score 21):

In the UK at least, someone who rides public transport without paying for a ticket is called a ['fare dodger'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fare_dodger)

> Fare Dodger - **noun**
>
> 1 - A person who deliberately avoids payment for public transport
>
> www.wiktionary.org

However this term does not apply to someone riding without consent on the back of a truck [or other vehicle].

Answer (score 19):

"Watch out for **Hop-Ons**!"

> Hop-ons are people who jump on to the back of the stair car for a free ride. They are a constant annoyance for the Bluth family members who must drive the stair car. [(source)](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Hop-ons)

[image: Stair Car Hop On]

If your vehicle was towing a small cabin, you would of course need to watch out for **Live-Ins**.

This is a running joke from the TV series *Arrested Development*, but "hop ons" would be an easily understood term for the situation. You even used it in the question!

Answer (score 14):

A free ride is a ***[hitch](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hitch):***

> - (informal) a ride obtained by hitchhiking.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: But is hitchhiking done without consent?

Comment: Hitchhiking is done *with* the consent of the driver since they need to stop for the hitchhiker to offer a ride.

Comment: *hitch a lift/ride*: to get a free ride in someone else's car. –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hitching). Hitchhiking requires consent. *hitching a ride* doesn't necessarily.

Comment: [Train surfing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_surfing) –Wiki. AKA = *train hitching*.

Answer (score 12):

There is an archaic legal term 'bilking' which can be used in the sense of using a service and not paying for it. It would not cover sitting in on someone's lecture, but it could be used for getting a free ride by not paying for a ticket.

[Here's the definition from The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bilking)

Comment: Bilking is still used in BrE for running off without paying for your taxi.

Comment: Also used, particularly by police, for filling up with fuel and driving off without paying for it.

Comment: Or running off without paying for a restaurant meal. The legal term is "making off without payment". It's an offence under the Theft Act 1978.

Answer (score 10):

**Free Rider** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/free+rider)

> *n.* a person who is supported by or seeks support from another without making an adequate return
>
> *"claimed that welfare recipients were a bunch of free riders with little or nothing to offer society"*
>
> <sub>***Synonyms*** bloodsucker, freeloader, leech, hanger-on, moocher, parasite, sponge, sponger</sub>

Comment: "Free rider" is a very commonly used term in the field of economics.

Answer (score 8):

When we used to grab onto the bumpers of unsuspecting cars for a tow while skateboarding, we called it <del>*hitching*</del> *skitching*.

Comment: There's a specific variation of this:  ***skitching***.

Comment: You're right. That's what we called it, not hitching. I totally forgot.

Comment: obligatory reference to the sega genisis game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQjgwVZEles

Answer (score 7):

"Tagging along" to or "observing" (e.g. "I'm just here to observe") a meeting implies you have the consent of at least one person in the meeting.

Being a "**fly on the wall**" is another common expression, meaning someone observing a meeting or conversation without being part of it in any way (including any effects on the conversation one's mere presence would have).

"Gatecrashing" or "crashing" refers to your desired concept as it applies to a party.
"Freerider" gets at the concept as applied to common carrier public transit.
"Stowaway" gets at the concept as applied to the parts of a vehicle not designed for passengers.
"Audit" refers to it in as applied to an educational class, and is usually done with the instructor's permission.
You are correct that "hijack" is a different concept which involves changing the direction or destination of whatever is being hijacked.

Comment: This is the only answer which actually addresses the "sitting in on a meeting" example!

Answer (score 7):

[Riding the rails](http://www.livinghistoryfarm.org/farminginthe30s/water_07.html) was the term, especially during the Great Depression, for "hopping a freight" to obtain free (though dangerous) transport across country.

There were variations.  "Trainhopping" was another general term, and [riding the rods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freighthopping#Riding_the_rods) was the term for the even more dangerous practice of riding on the truss and brake rods under the car (vs riding in an unlocked boxcar or riding atop a car).

[Fare dodging](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fare-dodging) is the somewhat more modern term for dodging the conductor or ticket taker on a train or bus.

Answer (score 5):

How about "tagging along", meaning "to go ​somewhere with a ​person or ​group, usually when they have not ​asked you to go with them.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tag-along

Comment: I'd say tagging along means your propelling yourself, not riding on somebody else's vehicle or expense.

Answer (score 4):

How about ***piggybacking***?

> link to or take advantage of (an existing system or body of work). *"they have piggybacked their own networks on to the system"*

<sub>OED</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is not a travel metaphor, but in college we would call that an **audit**.  You can **audit** a class which means you attend the class, but you don't get a grade or credit on your transcript.

Comment: Auditors often pay for the classes they audit.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically applying to subways (and possibly other modes of public transportation) is *turnstile jumping*.

This refers to the act of avoiding paying at a turnstile, which is a gate which opens when you deposit your fare, by jumping over it. I couldn't find a definition but it's widely used in [US newspapers](http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/subway-turnstile-jumpers-saving-loads-money-caught-study-shows-article-1.162403)

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

[***fare beater***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare+beater%2Cfare+beaters&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfare%20beater%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfare%20beaters%3B%2Cc0)/[***farebeater***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22farebeaters%22&oq=%22farebeaters%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...3288.7767.0.8596.15.15.0.0.0.0.389.2188.0j6j1j3.10.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..6.3.686.95dpNTo37jU)

> *n.* *Informal* One who avoids paying the fare for public transportation, especially the subway. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/farebeater)
>
> *noun* A person who illegally avoids paying a fare, as by entering a public bus through the exit door. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/farebeater)

[***fare evader***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fare+evaders&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfare%20evaders%3B%2Cc0)

> **fare evasion** or **ticket evasion** is the act of travelling on public transport in disregard of the law and/or regulation, having deliberately not purchased the required ticket to travel (having had the chance to do so.) [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fare_evasion)
>
> *As I am almost certainly the only person on this board who has ever arrested anyone for this activity, I can tell you with absolute certainty that in New York City, the legal term that the State of New York uses in the statute that describes this criminal offense is* ***theft of services**. The formal, but not the legal, term for the action (such as might be used in the press, or in a news release issued by the Transit Authority) is* ***fare evasion**, and a person who does not pay his required fare is a* ***fare evader**. The popular term universally used by police is* "***farebeating**", while a person who "beats the fare" is a* "***farebeater**."* [...] *I would consider "fare dodger" to be something those unfamiliar with the term might not immediately understand*.
>
> GreenWhiteBlue, January 14, 2009 - [WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fare-dodger.1237529/) (emphasis is mine.)

***deadhead***

> *Slang* A person who attends a performance, sports event, etc., or travels on a train, airplane, etc., without having paid for a ticket, especially a person using a complimentary ticket or free pass. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deadhead)
>
> One who has not paid for a ticket [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadhead)

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a bit away from your question,
but, if you observe a meeting or other activity without the consent —
and, especially, without the *knowledge* — of the participants,
you are ***snooping*** or ***spying***.  If you are primarily listening
without the consent and the knowledge of the speakers,
that's ***eavesdropping***.

On the other hand, if you overtly attend a meeting in order to obtain refreshments to which you aren't entitled, that's [***mooching***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mooch),
or simply ***stealing*** (or ***theft***).