# Word for attending lectures without seeking a degree

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would describe a person attending all the lectures of a program at some university but without seeking a degree. In the French language we call that an "Auditeur Libre" (ie. literally a "Free Auditor"), such persons are not registered as regular students. For example they are not required to take the end of term exams.

I'm struggling to find the appropriate English equivalent.

Any idea?

Comment: It's "auditor" at US colleges and universities also.

Comment: Apparently that goes for Canada and Australia also: ["4. (Education) Austral and US and Canadian: a registered student who attends a class that is not an official part of his course of study"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/auditor)

Comment: This is mentioned in another question: [Is there a term for a free ride without consent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302161)

Answer (score 8):

The word you are looking for its [**auditor**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/auditor):

> a university student registered for a course without credit and without obligation to do work assigned to the class.

Comment: "Auditor" is (as good as) unknown in this sense in the UK.

Comment: Indeed. If an "auditor" turned up to a class here they'd probably have been hired by the University to show up, sit in the back quietly, and report back on how well the lecturer is lecturing.

Comment: Extremely common in the US. At least, I've done this a number of times, and no professor has ever failed to understand what I meant when I asked if they would mind me auditing the course. Is there a UK term for this, then?

Answer (score 2):

Australian universities usually refer to an ***audit student*** or a ***non-assessed student***.

Answer (score 1):

Auditor is the word you are probably looking for. However... I find that the word 'auditor' is more often associated with someone in the accounting field. To avoid that confusion, I would refer to that student as someone who is auditing this  or that course.

Comment: I agree that the word "auditor" usually means something else.  Be careful to use it only when there is no possibility of confusion.

Comment: I had the same impression ! At least if american folks are familiar with that, this will reduce the chances of confusion

Answer (score 1):

You would be a *non-matriculating* student. To audit a course typically means to take the course without credit. A non-matriculating student takes courses for credit without wanting a degree.

Comment: I corrected what appeared to be a typo, but other than that, I concur with the answer, and the distinction it makes between auditing a course and being a non-matriculated student.  A non-matriculated student may have finished a degree and found that he/she lacks certain courses for the next degree.  That student signs up for the course wherever it is convenient and makes up the deficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, [***non-degree [seeking] student***](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/auditeur-libre.676648/)

> non-degree seeking (non-matriculated) student is one who is enrolled on a semester-by-semester or course-by-course basis and has not been accepted as a regular student pursuing a degree. [University of Buffalo](http://undergrad-catalog.buffalo.edu/policies/admission/matriculated.shtml)

Comment: Thanks, highly relevant answer I'll go with auditor because I do not want to emphasize the fact that the person is a student, but rather emphasize the fact that the person attended certain courses.